# openapi generates minimum and maximum which is not working properly

Tags: spring, spring-boot, openapi-generator, spring-validator, spring-validation

openapi minimum/maximum

```
put:
      summary: add
      operationId: add
      requestBody:
        description: value
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Value'
components:
  schemas:
    Value:
      type: object
      required:
        - value
      properties:
        value:
          type: integer
          format: int64
          minimum: 1
          maximum: 999
```

generates

```
@Min(1L) @Max(999L) 
  public Long getValue() {
    return value;
  }
```

Which is not working properly. I try

```
mockMvc.perform(
                        put(RESOURCE_URL + "/1/add")
                                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                .content("{\"value\":0}"))
```

I've no idea is it API problem or spring `@Min(1L) @Max(999L)` validator problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dependencies {
  ...
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
}
```